# how to setup this git workflow?

Tags: git, workflow, git-rebase, git-workflow

I want to be able to setup the following git workflow but it confusing as to which are the correct commands to use - rebase, remote, etc?

1. Clone an open source project where I only have read only access to their git repo
2. Make changes to the project and save those changes to my private github repo - lets call that 'development'
3. Once dev changes are stable move them over to 'staging'
4. Once 'staging' has been tested then move the changes to 'production'
5. Sync the remote open source project say weekly as its always changing and then start the whole process again.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need a copy of he source for staging and production? Why don't just use tags in development to formally release artefacts so you could say "1.2.3 is ready to staging environment", "1.2.3 did well with tests, it's now a production deliverable"? if you find a bug in 1.2.3, you should fix it in your baseline (development) possibly checking out the tag to reproduce the problem.

Comment: there are files that should only be in production like cache settings, database settings and max memory settings - so only have those in the production area and everything else in the dev/staging

Answer (score 1):

```
# clone, create and change to branch development
git clone git://the/open/source/project.git
git checkout -b development

# make changes and commit
git add ...
git commit -m '...'

# several commits later, create a branch named staging and change to it
git checkout -b staging

# after testing, create a branch named production and change to it
git checkout -b production

# syncing ( assuming the remote to be named origin and the branch is named master )
git checkout master
git fetch origin master
git merge origin/master

# repeat the process
```

Comment: -1 you forgot "git add", you forgot something like "git remote add github <url>". And finally, the merge should be after checking out development branch, not master.

Comment: You could have edited the answer. That is why there is an `edit` button! A `git clone` automatically adds a remote tracking branch. The user may want to have a `master` branch which is exactly like the remote. Hence the merge to `master`.

Comment: Ah! My bad. Apologies, @mrrtnn. :-(